# Tooltip for disabled tab

Tags: extjs

When the tab is enabled tooltip works, but when the tab is not showing off tooltip.
This is tab init:

```
new Fc.Components.SelectionTab({
   tabConfig: {
   disabled: true,
      tooltip: Fc.Lang.app.messages.not_register
   },
   cmp: this
});
```

Comment: When your tab is disabled, you don't want the tooltip to show ? is that right ? Or you want your tooltip to show whatever your tab is disabled or not ?

Comment: Me need show tooltip when tab is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the style property `pointer-events` of the component you are mentioning.

In your example that would be:

```
new Fc.Components.SelectionTab({
   tabConfig: {
       disabled: true,
       style: {
           pointerEvents: 'all'
       },
       tooltip: Fc.Lang.app.messages.not_register
   },
   cmp: this
});
```